# Error Application Layout Component of angular components in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-pub

Trying to implement the new released application layout component of angular components in my project.
Even after importing `import'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';` dart throws an error for `MaterialIconComponent, MaterialPersistentDrawerDirective, MaterialTemporaryDrawerComponent,`

```
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling my_app|web/main.dart...
[Error from Dart2JS on my_app|web/main.dart]:
web\main.template.dart:16:1:
Can't read 'package:my_app/views/app_component/app_component.template.dart' (Could not find asset my_app|lib/views/app_component/app_component.template.dart.).
import 'package:my_app/views/app_component/app_component.template.dart' as i1;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Error from Dart2JS on my_app|web/main.dart]:
web\packages\my_app\views\app_component\app_component.dart:25:5:
Not a compile-time constant.
    MaterialIconComponent,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Dart2JS on my_app|web/main.dart]:
3 warning(s) suppressed in package:my_app.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:07.975139 to compile my_app|web/main.dart.
Build failed.
```

Error: mediator

```
  Found 3 mismatching dependencies on package:build:
* angular2 requires  ^0.9.0
* angular_components->angular requires  ^0.10.0
* angular_components->angular->angular_compiler requires  ^0.10.0
```

Package dependencies in the project

```
dependencies:
angular2: "^3.1.0"
angular_components: "^0.6.0-alpha+3"
browser: "^0.10.0+2"
dart_to_js_script_rewriter: "^1.0.3"
firebase: "^4.1.0"
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's related to the layout component. Try closing the IDE, delete the `.pub` directory, run `pub upgrade`, and start the IDE again.

Comment: Nothing changed by deleting .pub directory, running pub upgrade the error still throws the same.

Comment: What Dart version are you using?

Comment: How can I check, that which version is running.

Comment: `dart --version`

Comment: Dart VM version: 1.24.2

Comment: Can you please check the `angular_components` version in `pubspec.lock`

Comment: It's the latest version: 0.5.3+1

Comment: I don't think this version contains `MaterialIconComponent` or the layout cimponents, Try 0.6.0-alpha+3 instead.

Comment: Package angular has no versions that match 4.0.0-alpha+3 derived from:
- angular_components 0.6.0-alpha+3 depends on version 4.0.0-alpha+3
- angular_forms 0.1.0 depends on version ^4.0.0-alpha

Comment: Ensure the dependency constraint ob angular allows that version. If this is not enough, comment out all other dependencies and add them one-by-one to find out which ine causes the conflict. You can also try https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pub_mediator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dependencies:
  angular: ^4.0.0-alpha+3
  angular_components: ^0.6.0-alpha+3
```

Comment: angular: "^4.0.0-alpha+3"
   angular2: "^3.1.0"
   angular_components: "^0.6.0-alpha+3"

Comment: `angular2: "^3.1.0"` needs to be removed. `angular2` was renamed to `angular` in version 4.